# Get UINavigationBar delegate to allow "back", with a nice animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Scenario on an iPhone:

The user taps the back button, the `UINavigationBar` delegate method (implemented in a subclass of `UINavigationController`) returns `YES`, like this:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    // Verify stuff...

    return YES;
}
```

Now, according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), it's the app's responsibility to keep the nav bar and the contents in sync, and the place to do that is in the delegate method

```
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
```

The problem is, that `didPopItem` is only called after the nav bar's pop animation sequence is finished, so if I call `[self popViewControllerAnimated: NO]` there, the net result is that first the nav bar slides back, then the contents.

And that just looks wrong.

If I call the navigation controller's `pop...` in the delegate `shouldPop...` method, I get an error message to the effect that I am overlapping animations, and the final state is not clean.

So my question is, is there another way to get the UINavigationController to change contents, preferably with a nice animation in sync with the nav bar's, but without creating confusion between the nav bar and the navigation controller?

The target OS is iOS 4.2 and later.

I am aware that I could just create another left button in place of the back button, but I found it cleaner to use a delegate, plus, I get a "real" back button, which is what I want.

Comment: Y u want to call didPopItem Method before  nav bar's pop animation sequence as u had writter in 3rd paragrah..What u wana to do can u please make it clear ur 3rd paragh whihc is u think ur main quetion

Comment: Why are you using a separate navigation bar with a `UINavigationController` instead of using the one it provides?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a UINavigationController, you do not need to manage this yourself. You will save yourself a lot of trouble by simply using the UINavigationController. It will take care of popping the content view along with the navigation bar items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Imagine you have viewControllerA and viewControllerB. viewControllerA is the first one and doesn't need a navigationBar and viewControllerB does.

On the method `viewWillAppear` in viewControllerA put the code:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and when popping the viewControllerB you do so with animation. Both animations will be in sync automagically.

Don't know if this is valid for iOS4.2